# System.out.print(variable) cannot find symbol

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am new to java.
I am just experimenting.
When I try to convert this code with javac it gives my an error

```
error: Cannot find symbol
  System.out.print(res);           
                   ^
symbol: variable res
```

Here is the full code:

```
class forarray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr[][] = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 5, 6, 7 } };
        for (int res = 0; res + arr[1][2] <= 10; res++) {
            if (res == 2) {
                res += 15;
            } else {
                res += 1;
            }
        }
        System.out.print(res);
    }
}
```

Comment: Look into variable scope.

Comment: You define variable res in loop but try to use it out of loop

Comment: Thank you. I resolved that issue, but now there are other issues.                                                                                                                                                                                                                               class test {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  int res = 0;
   int arr[][] = {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 6, 7}};
  for(res + arr[1][2] <= 10;res++);
   if(res == 2) {
     res += 15;
   }else{
     res += 1;
    }
   }  
  System.out.print(res);
 }
}

Comment: Add a semicolon after "for("  to indicate the missing initializer. However, a better solution is to use a while loop instead. You are misusing the control variable of the for loop. If a for loop doesn't depend entirely on a single variable, it's usually clearer to use another control structure, such as a while loop.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried with a while loop and now it works.